# Azure Topic Subscription Configure to Run only 1 Instance at a time

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have created a Azure service bus topic subscription which receives a message form another http trigger function app and insert information into a database.

Every message I receive has an ID and based on the ID, I decide to either add a new record or updating existing one.

Problem is happening when 2 messages with the same ID are received at the same time and ends up creating 2 database records.

Is there any way to configure topic subscription function to run only 1 instance at a time? I don't have control on the function app which send

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to configure topic subscription function to run only 1 instance at a time?

You can configure everything like number of instances to be running, number of messages to be processing, number of calls and sessions, etc., in `host.json` file. All the attributes of `host.json` related to Azure Functions Service bus trigger bindings are available in this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus?tabs=in-process,extensionv5,extensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp#hostjson-settings) reference.

For your requirements such as processing 1 message at a time, you can define the following attributes to `1` in the `host.json` file:

```
"maxConcurrentSessions": 1,
"maxMessageBatchSize": 1, 
"maxConcurrentCalls": 1,
"messageHandlerOptions": {  
"maxConcurrentCalls": 1  
},
```

Normally, Azure Functions will process the messages in multiple and in parallel. So, the attributes like `maxConcurrentSessions`, `maxConcurrentCalls` plays the major role to define number of sessions and calls to be processed for every instance.

```
"batchOptions": {  
"maxMessageCount": 1  
}
```

Above complete configuration of `host.json` will do processing of 2nd message only after the execution of 1st message in the Service bus topic subscription azure function.

Comment: You have specified 2 host.josn settings, which one I need to use?

Comment: edited the 2nd code block. Use both in same `host.json` file